# Viewpager expanded searchview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I implemented  SearchView inside my android app which uses toolbar, SlidingTabLayout and ViewPager that holds Fragments.

but the SearchView is collapsed and reset the TextView which time i swipe to another fragment

how i can keep the SearchView expanded during the swiping to search multiple fragments

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);
     mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
     searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSearchMenuItem);
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
     return true;
}
```

Layout :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Comment: Maybe you can try setting setHasOptionsMenu(false); in the child Fragments? And leave it active in the parent.